# Excel: Append table to another where the columns are the same, but rows differ

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have struggeled for hours to append one table to another in Excel. I have tried 1000 variations of VLOOKUP but it didnt work. The columns (metrics) are the same for all my tables, but the rows differ (members dropped out). I want to append the new columns to the old table and get a wide table for all years.

Table 1 (2017)

```
|member|revenue|sales|profit|
|   1  |  10   |  20 |  10  |
|   2  |  10   |  20 |  10  |
|   3  |  10   |  20 |  10  |
|   4  |  10   |  20 |  10  |
|   5  |  10   |  20 |  10  |
|   6  |  10   |  20 |  10  |
|   7  |  10   |  20 |  10  |
```

Table 2 (2018, some members dropped out)

```
|member|revenue|sales|profit|
|   1  |  40   |  60 |  80  |
|   3  |  40   |  60 |  80  |
|   4  |  40   |  60 |  80  |
|   6  |  40   |  60 |  80  |
|   7  |  40   |  60 |  80  |
```

Result: Append all columns of Table 2 to table 1

```
2017                         2018
|member|revenue|sales|profit|revenue|sales|profit|
|   1  |  10   |  20 |  10  |  40   |  60 |  80  |
|   2  |  10   |  20 |  10  |  NA   |  NA |  NA  |
|   3  |  10   |  20 |  10  |  40   |  60 |  80  |
|   4  |  10   |  20 |  10  |  40   |  60 |  80  |
|   5  |  10   |  20 |  10  |  NA   |  NA |  NA  |
|   6  |  10   |  20 |  10  |  40   |  60 |  80  |
|   7  |  10   |  20 |  10  |  40   |  60 |  80  |
```

Comment: *I have tried 1000 variations of VLOOKUP but it didnt work.* It's strange. Show your variant(s). And specify the posession of source/result on the worksheet.

Comment: PS. Maybe you do not set the last argument of VLOOKUP to FALSE?

Comment: My guess is you didn't include the final,  optional,  parameter for "exact match"

Comment: So for one column it works: `=SVERWEIS(H11;D27:E33;2;)`,  But the moment that I specify several columns, its now working: `=SVERWEIS(H11;D27:E33;{2;3;4};)` I specifed several columns in the curly brackets because I read in a post you have to do this if you want to append several columns. And I fixed the column with `$`so that wehn I pull the formula over it doesnt shift the search column.

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose: So when I specify the last parameter (2 for FALSE - Exact match) it still is not working

Comment: @LargoTerranova I'm not sure the inner {2;3;4} works for excel - the only reference I found was for google sheets. You just need to do the formula for each column (i.e., the first column have '2' in the column field, the second column have '3' in the column field, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**N.B.**

Write this array formula in Cell `E218` fill right then press `F2` & finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. Then Fill it down to get the results.

```
{=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A218,$A$210:$D$215,{2,3,4},FALSE),"No Match")}
```

**How it works:**

- `{2,3,4}` reads Column 2 to 4 in order 
  of an **Array Constants**, which are 
  often used in array formulas to 
  manipulate several values at once, 
  rather than a single value.
- Adjust cell references in the formula 
  as needed.
- You may replace `No Match` with 
  `blanks`.

Comment: Interesting, I replicated your tables and could not get it working. I used the following formula: `=WENNFEHLER(SVERWEIS(A218;$A$210:$D$215;{2;3;4};FALSCH);"No Match")` . When I'm finished typing, I press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. It makes an Array transformation. The Resulting table has the correct values in the first row but the other two are all "NO Match". I tried fixing the column searchvalue in VLOOKUP ($A218) but then it has the results of the first column in the second and third as well. What am I missing?

Comment: @LargoTerranova, I'm sure you are struggling with improper execution of an Array formula. Read the instruction carefully & Follow will work 100%. My Screen shot is the evidence  that it's working ☺

Comment: @LargoTerranova, do this ,,, Write Formula finish with `ENTER`,,, `Fill RIGHT`,,, `PRESS F2` then finish with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`. you get `1st row` then fill `DOWN`. You get all rows. Or share the Workbook on cloud i'll solve the live sheet for U. ☺

Comment: @LargoTerranova, glad to  help you,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by @Rajesh S should work. You will have to first select all three applicable cells in a row together and then enter the Array Formula in the formula bar. This way {2,3,4} from the array formula get spread across 3 columns in a horizontal array.

In case you are not comfortable with Array Formula and you have just the two tables you can simply manipulate COLUMN()-COLUMN(fixed reference two columns behind) in VLOOKUP to generate 2,3,4 only once and you shall be able to join the two tables.

If you have a need to stack more tables one below other, for example in future you might even add 2019, 2020 and so on one below the other, then you may also like to consider below solution.

In this example base Table1 is in $A$3:$D$9, Table2 $A$11:$D$15 and Table3  $A$17:$D$21.

Please use First Row as a helper row and put the Cell1:Cell2 dimensions of your respective tables therein exactly in the way excel formula understands cell reference as for example $A$11:$D$15

Now put the following formula in E3 and drag it down across and below up to the intended cells.

Your tables shall be joined one next to another. In future if you add more tables just put the respective dimensions on the helper row as applicable.

The column number manipulation to generate sequence 2,3,4 for VLOOKUP is only going to work if you start your formula in Column E. If you starting in any other column a formula alteration would be needed to correctly re-generate sequence 2,3,4.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A3,INDIRECT(E$1),IF(MOD(COLUMN(),3)=0,3,IF(MOD(COLUMN(),3)=1,4,2)),FALSE),"NA")
```

[image]